# flutter: can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'

Tags: flutter, generics, dart

I am trying to create generic `PopupMenuButton` to use every place that i want to use so i create this generic class:

```
class PopupMenuHelper<T> {
Widget showPopupMenu() {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(cardColor: Colors.greenAccent),
      child: PopupMenuButton<T>(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
            )),
        onSelected: (value) {
          print("value:$value");
          callBack(T);
        },
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem<T>(value: T, child: Text("Profile")),
          PopupMenuItem<T>(value: T, child: Text("Profile2")),
        ],
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        offset: Offset(0, 100),
        elevation: 8,
```

In `PopupMenuItem` i declare item as a T type but in value i got error:

```
The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

How can i fix ?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't pass T as a value in PopupMenuItem constructor, but the actual object you are referring to, of type T. You can pass it as a parameter of showPopupMenu or in the constructor of PopupMenuHelper.

Comment: Can you write an example? @Vardiak